# Do I have first rights to slaughter on the day I buy a child or parent animal?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, slaughter-shochet-shecht

## [Rule:](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.22.28)

> וְשׁ֖וֹר אוֹ־שֶׂ֑ה אֹת֣וֹ וְאֶת־בְּנ֔וֹ לֹ֥א תִשְׁחֲט֖וּ בְּי֥וֹם אֶחָֽד׃
>
> However, no animal from the herd or from the flock shall be slaughtered on the same day with its young.

If I purchase someone’s cow’s young [or vice versa] and we both want to slaughter today, who gets the right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De’ah 16:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.16.6?lang=bi) writes that as soon as one sells an animal, he may not slaughter its offspring/parent that day, as the sale is done with the intent that the purchaser may slaughter the animal he has bought immediately.

> שמיד כשמכר לראשון לא היה יכול לשחוט את שנשאר בידו שהלוקח לקח על מנת לשחוט מיד

Thus, the first right to slaughter resides with the buyer.

Comment: Seemingly, they could stipulate otherwise at the time of the sale if they wanted to.

Answer (score 6):

Tosefta, Chulin 5 (quoted by Rashi, Chulin 82a לענין; and quoted in Riff):

> הלוקח מבעל הבית הוא קודם לבעל הבית שמתחלה לא לקחו אלא על מנת כן
>
> One who purchases a cow from someone may be the first to slaughter, for that was his intention in buying it.